# What do you call the interconnecting bits of a puzzle piece in English?

Tags: single-word-requests

This is hard to describe, but I'm curious about what the proper word is for these thingies in English.

So I searched for a picture on Google and circled what I'm referring to with red:

[image: Puzzle piece with the questionable parts circled with red.]

Comment: My brain has decided they're called "knobs", but I've absolutely no proof anyone else calls them that.

Comment: We always called them "bobbles" (or perhaps "blobbles").

Comment: Pretty obscure.  I don't think most English speakers know a word for that.

Comment: @Joe That was my first thought. I love doing puzzles and I've never called them anything.

Comment: Jigsaw enthusiasts might have a word but I wouldn't know what to call them in normal English.

Comment: The ends of the pieces of toy train tracks are called "male" and "female" where they connect.  The connection itself is called a "mating connection."  I would think the same concept would apply to jigsaw puzzles.

Comment: This should be closed because it shows no evidence of research.

Comment: @curiousdannii The accepted answer shows lots of evidence of research. Why would you want to close it?

Comment: @Venemo [It's *questions* that need to show evidence of research.](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/5459/59258)

Comment: I'm a bit confused by this discussion, I would just call them ''links''.  You use them to link multiple pieces together.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

This kind of puzzle is called a *jigsaw puzzle*, and [the corresponding Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jigsaw_puzzle) uses the terms ***tabs*** and ***blanks***. (The parts you've circled are the *tabs*.)

Looking further throws up many citations for "tabs": [this book on DNA computing](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=N-rpYPLy23EC&pg=PA11&dq=jigsaw+tabs) calls them *jigsaw tabs* (and *pockets*), [this book on programming](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=l_EkwuQf9CkC&pg=PA214&dq=jigsaw+tabs) also mentions *interlocking tabs*, [this issue of *Make* magazine](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=lSdLAQAAIAAJ&q=jigsaw+tabs) calls them *jigsaw tabs* (and *slots*), and there are [lots of other books](http://www.google.com/search?q=jigsaw+tabs&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). There seems to be more consensus on what to call the circled pieces you want (*tabs*) and less on what to call the other kind (*blanks*, *pockets*, *slots*, *indents*...).

You can also trawl through search results for [jigsaw (tab OR tongue OR outie)](http://www.google.com/search?q=jigsaw+%28tabs+OR+tongues+OR+outies%29&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), to compare the answers suggested. (Need to look at each result individually to make sure the word is used in the right context. In fact *most* results aren't about the context we want. :-))

However, it is also a fact that there is no universally accepted terminology. For instance, [this book on the history of jigsaw puzzles](http://books.google.com/books?id=-uXglfPvx9QC&q=tabs) says on page 10 that

> Despite a few attempts at a comprehensive classification of piece shapes and cutting designs, there is still no generally accepted nomenclature. Manufacturers use a variety of terms, as do puzzlers. Puzzle pieces can have "loops" and "sockets", "knobs" and "holes", "tabs" and "slots", "keys" and "locks", or any of several other alternative designations.

Comment: @Venemo: Unfortunately, I just updated my answer to show that *blanks* may not be universal. :-) But *tabs* seems to be used widely.

Comment: How do you call the act of connecting the pieces, i.e. "some repeating patterns makes it harder to *compose* the puzzle"?

Comment: Well according to the wiki link you provided, I've learned it's "assembling puzzles"

Comment: Just as a curiosity - I have **never, ever, ever** heard them referred to as either tabs or blanks ..... and I work in a related software engineering field.

Comment: @JoeBlow: What does software engineering have to do with jigsaw puzzles? And what have you heard them referred to as? When I did the search back when I posted the answer, I did find an overwhelming majority of sources use "tabs", as I said in the answer.

Comment: Hi Shree! - every single jigsaw puzzle (since perhaps 1995, I'm not sure) is made using software. The only engineers working in "jigsaw construction" are, indeed, programmers. Other than a handful of hand-made wooden jigsaw cutters, the only people who would use "jigsaw terminology" are programmers. (Note you reference a programming book?) Are you a native English speaker by the way?  Regarding google searches, I find they have no relation at all to actual-usage on the street; you tend to find a few formalish references.  Also, see my comment on Matt's answer below.

Comment: It would be interesting to indeed just telephone ravensburger and ask them what the hell word they use!  (I bet for the new spherical technology they have come up with something typically german and accurate! :)

Comment: @JoeBlow: You didn't answer: What have you heard them referred to as? :-) And in any case the number of people *playing* jigsaw puzzles is much larger than those *constructing* them, so it's not clear that the terminology used by programmers should be taken more seriously than that used by those marketing, playing, or studying jigsaw puzzles.

Comment: Hi Shree, like I said I'm wondering if you are a native English speaker? Regarding what I have heard them referred to as, as I have repeated a number of times (also see my loooong answer), that even amongst aficionados, even in the games industry (eg, at Hasbro, etc), there **is no term** and they are referred to in **an adhoc manner** (exactly as JustinY pointed out, way back when). (Regarding the last sentence of your comment, it's a non-sequitor; I'm not saying anything should be "taken more seriously" [as opposed to sarcastically? what?] I'm just discussing how different groups use it.

Comment: @JoeBlow: Sorry I didn't notice you had posted an answer: I was only notified of your comments here, and I additionally looked at your comment on Matt's answer because you pointed me to it, and in neither place did I see your view that there is no consistent term. That may well be the case, but as the answer above shows, at least one term that exists is "tabs", and it has enough support in books. Other terms may also have some support. To take X more seriously than Y is to give it more importance than Y.

Comment: @JoeBlow: Finally, I'm not sure why you're seeking personal information about me. (You can look at my profile to see my other answers on this website.) If you really need to know, I can tell you (English is the medium of all my education, the language I'm most comfortable in, and I find the notion of "native speaker" one that imperfectly captures one's proficiency in a language, e.g. given that it's native speakers who make more mistakes of the *your/you're*, *their/they're* type), but this is a strange question to encounter on the internet.

Comment: Hi Shree - you may have misunderstood me, I was wondering what if any the common term is in your native language!  :)

Comment: @JoeBlow: Ah ok. :-) Sorry for any misunderstanding; I wasn't in the best mood yesterday. I actually agree that there aren't any common terms in English either: I've updated the answer to say that.

Comment: I am never in a good mood, and I think pretty much EVERYTHING ever said on the internet is misunderstood  :)  Cheers!

Comment: If an "innie" is a "blank", what do you call a side with neither innie nor outie?

Comment: Please lets all make this "Loop & Socket". That is just super catchy. Moving forward, lets all agree that is the correct terminology!!!

Comment: Not having thought of this before, I would have guessed *tabs* and *notches* (they aren't really *slots*, which are what tabs are often inserted into).

Comment: I have never heard ''tabs'' and ''blanks'' before, I would just call them ''links'' as they are used to link several pieces together and link is common English.

Answer (score 25):

Speaking as a fully-qualified jigsaw puzzle solver, I can say that the standard word is an [outie](http://www.learnglish.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/english/6138/jigsaw-puzzle-pieces). Terminology shared with belly-buttons, except normally only *jigsaw outies* interlock with *innies*.

According to [this glossary](http://www.puzzlehistory.com/gloss.htm) people also call them *tabs* or *knobs*, but the problem there is they don't have an obvious term for the corresponding *innie*, so I'd stick with *outie*. A jigsaw is a game anyway, so there's nothing wrong with using childish terminology.

Comment: *Innie* and *outie* sounds a bit more casual than *tab* and *blank*.

Comment: Oh, before your edit I thought that "fully-qualified jigsaw puzzle solver" meant that you had participated in some state-/national-level jigsaw puzzle-solving competitions or something like that. :-) I would be disappointed to learn that no such thing exists.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: Nah - my qualifications aren't quite so formally-recognised. But I did spend a lot of time in hospital throughout my childhood, and there wasn't much else to do there for several weeks every year!

Answer (score 8):

All I can suggest is *tongue*, as in the joint in carpentry known as *tongue and groove*.

Comment: You make me think, "dog" wold be a great term here.  (Since it is, exactly that, a dog.)  I wonder does anyone know, what's the female version of a dog called? Probably a sailor or old-days carpenter would know this?

Comment: A 'female version of a dog' is surely a bitch @Fattie

Comment: You know @Clare "dog" also means (ask, say, a sailor or engineer), a "projection" that is used to grab or stop something - picture something like, oh, a coat-hook or a stick of metal poking out.  Example, imagine a shuttle or something that whips along on some steel rail: at each end there's like a lump of metal sticking out (think like a dowel) that stops it moving at the end, you call that thing a "dog"........  indeed it occurs to me the opposite of that type of "dog" would be a "notch" probably.

Answer (score 7):

I believe 'tenon' and 'mortice' are the appropriate technical terms.

Comment: That's interesting, considering everything else suggested on this page doesn't mention either. What leads you to this conclusion?

Comment: @MattЭллен: I don't know about jigsaw puzzles, but these are the preferred terms in woodworking http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mortise_and_tenon. I, personally, would find it natural to borrow terms from woodworking (if they didn't exist already). And so, I +1'd it. But that's just what *I'm* inclined to do.

Comment: but then, I'm not an expert at woodworking either. Though "mortice and tenon" is a very specific kind of joint, the same terms are used for a few other types of joints.

Comment: +1: Given that jigsaw puzzles originated in woodworking, I think this is a plausible conjecture. I am used to seeing it spelled *mortise*, however, but either is correct.

Comment: It is exactly, precisely correct that tenon and mortice **are** appropriate technical terms.  I don't know if you can say they are **"the"** technical terms.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the Wikipedia article on [jigsaw puzzles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jigsaw_puzzle#Puzzle_pieces), they use the word *tab*:

> Some fully interlocking puzzles have pieces all of a similar shape, with **rounded tabs** out on opposite ends, with corresponding blanks cut into the intervening sides to receive the tabs of adjacent pieces.

(emphasis added)

Comment: Who cares what someone writing on Wikipedia, used **to describe** the issue?  So what?  The person writing there is not saying "the word usually used is 'xyz', the person writing there is simply describing them.  (Exactly as the OP describes them in some other way.)

Answer (score 3):

There's a very important point here:

**In English, it's reasonably common that - strangely enough - there IS NO WORD for a certain fairly common thing.**

(There's possibly actually a term for this phenomenon - like "grasp words" or "thingy words" or something.)

Note for example, Justin's first comment on the question - which is totally correct and typical.

I have never, ever, ever heard them referred to in any way, in English, other than something like "the thingy that sticks out" "the hole thing on the edge" "the whatever tonguey thingy"

Note that even if you look at software (like the actual computer code, in c# of whatever, relating to machines that cut puzzles) you just seeterms like TheOutThingy OneOfTheHoleThings and so on.

Again - in my opinion - among English speakers it's reasonably common that - strangely enough - there IS NO WORD for a certain fairly common thing.  We stick with "thingy phrases" and sort of deliberately don't settle on a word.  IMO the - thingies - on jigsaws are a perfect example of this.

So, IMO, there is literally no word for these in English - even among jigsaw aficionados or in the games industry.

{A small point: Note too that the jigsaw-puzzle industry is largely German, as it happens, so you could possibly look to the German language for guidance here, if you're trying to "decide on" what we should all call these thingies.}

{Another small point - note that, wildly confusingly, "jigsaw puzzles" are called "jigsaw puzzles" in certain English speaking areas, BUT, are called .. wait for it .. "puzzles" in other English speaking areas.}

Comment: Thanks, nice thought! I've already settled with 'tab' and 'blank' (because they were shorter), but it's always nice to see more insight into English :)

Comment: Right. In my family (British English) we've always called them "the sticky-out bits". Although there might be specific terms which are technically correct, they're not likely to be widely recognised.

Comment: yeah "sticky-out bits" is the highly technical term  :-)

Comment: German is just as confused: Noppe, Nase, Knopf, Zapfen, Ausbuchtung for 'outies' [~bobble, nose, button, tongue in the woodworking sense, bulge] and 'Loch (Nasenloch, Knopfloch), Einbuchtung' [hole x3, indentation] for the other one (I'd go with tab and hole myself).

Comment: I would just call them ''links'' if I had to use a word in English.

Answer (score 3):

Another way of calling it would be **male plug** or **male connector**.

I'm coding a puzzle game right now and I've found this thread while searching for an appropriate variable name. I've decided to go with plug, because I was looking for a generic term that describes both tabs and blanks, innie and outie, ricky and morty etc. **Plugs can be male or female**, where male corresponds to tab and female to blank.

And here's a little code for fellow software developers:

```
enum PlugType {
    MALE, FEMALE
}

enum PlugSide {
    TOP, BOTTOM, LEFT, RIGHT
}
```

Comment: While this is interesting, it does not answer the question.

Comment: In my humble opinion it does, as one way you can call this thing is a plug (which answers the question). Maybe it's not a correct term as far as manufacturers call it, but I know a lot of software developers visit this site for the same reason I did and I wanted to help them. Maybe I went to far with placing the code here :)

Comment: The question was specifically about the extended, or male portions. If you edit your answer to clearly indicate the coupled terms *male or female plugs*, I would upvote it. But not as it is, with just *plugs*. And I actually liked your coding example.

Comment: OP here. My original question was also for a puzzle game that I coded. :) If you're interested, you can find it here: https://github.com/Venemo/puzzle-master/ I went with the accepted "tabs" and "blanks" but I guess "plug" could also work as a more generic term.

Comment: Funny That you ended up here for the same reason as me... Here is my Enum: Public Enum EdgeType As Integer
    None = 0
    Male = 1
    Female = 2
End Enum

Comment: or "boy" and "girl". or in psychology, "extraverted" and "introverted". or in alchemy, element 1 (fire) is male and element 2 (earth) is female, which is more obvious with the roman numerals I and II.

Answer (score 2):

I am a woodworker and I often happen to explain that I craft [puzzles](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/261935/96006) without those joints. Native speakers do not assimilate those Wikipedia's *tabs and blanks*. So forget them if you want a layman to grasp the meaning the first time. Instead, I use figurative **onion** or **bulb** or protruding onion-shaped **bulge**.

Edit. Another comparison is a **peninsula** contrasted to the **bay** or **fjord** to which it fits.

Comment: Hello, Przemyslaw. Please check at the Help Center and on ELU.Meta. ELU deals with standard (widely recognised) usages only, not novel suggestions, however ingenious / appealing. If you can find a reasonable reference supporting your figurative usages here, it will make this a valid answer.  Note that 'thumbs' and 'bays' looks a reasonable suggestion ... but they're not idiomatic terms (with jigsaws ... they _are_ with lakes), so off-topic.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth No, I have learnt these usages through paving my way to the clearest explanations to others. But if it stays here maybe it will become a source for reference:-) BTW I do not have such a visual inverse-bulb term for the female socket. The suggested "bay" seems one of my favorite.