# Is there a term for the inability to find a word which is then substituted with a "funnier" word?

Tags: phrases, expressions

Take this sentence:

> "If people are lost when they start out, they usually just keep getting...loster."
>   — from "Don't Make Me Think"

Obviously "loster" isn't a word, but I see this turn of phrase quite often. How would I describe this formula?

Comment: I believe there is no specific term, for when you create out of thin air a humorous form of a word.  (So, basically by adding "-er" or "-est" or another suffix, where it is unexpected.)  I don't think there's a specific term.  "wordplay" does *not* have the right connotation - what you're talking about is more dada, a bit silly.

Comment: reminds me of Buffyspeak:  http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BuffySpeak

Comment: Please Google "Buffy speak". It'll get you.. things, like, made up words, and more words? Tell me what you find. :)

Comment: **Ultron:** Everyone creates the thing they dread. Men of peace create engines of war, invaders create avengers. People create... smaller people? Uhh... children! [Chuckles]. Lost the word there. Children, designed to supplant them. To help them... end.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Term for using "thingy-esque" phrases rather than a common word](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/160351/term-for-using-thingy-esque-phrases-rather-than-a-common-word)

Comment: A nonce word? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonce_word

Comment: @SteveBennett If the question was worded slightly differently, you'd have the perfect answer for it.

Comment: Mmm. Incidentally, the linguistic term for this process is probably [overgeneralization](http://grammar.about.com/od/grammarfaq/a/What-Is-Linguistics.htm). Not 100% of this example qualifies though. "Loster" actually seems borderline acceptable (particularly since there isn't an alternative single-word form), compared to the always-unacceptable "rided" etc.

Comment: Just for the record, [anomia or anomic aphasia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anomic_aphasia) is the clinical term for the inability to recall a word you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

The intentional use of bad or incorrect grammar to make a humorous point is called a "solecism".

> This was the most unkindest cut of all.
>   --*Julius Caesar*, Shakespeare

Answer (score 1):

The term is 'Paronym' but the terms most striking and of greater currency, are

- Malapropism

  and
- Dogberryism

It is the act of using an incorrect word in place of one that is similar in pronunciation and the effect is ludicrous. The words owe their origin to the characters of the selfsame names of Mrs. Malaprop (a character in 'The Rivals' by Sheridan) or Dogberry (from " Much Ado About Nothing "). The mistakes as such are named after them.

To Mrs.Malaprop, an alligator can replace allegory and one may hear her say, " Illiterate (obliterate) him quite from your memory".

Dogberry is no better. He says, " Our Watch, sir, comprehended  two auspicious persons "(apprehended/ suspicious). President George Bush is a great artist of Malapropism.

Some examples:

- A rolling stone gathers no moth(moss).
- Having one wife is called monotony
  (monogamy).
- Patience is a virgin(virtue).
- He is a man of great statue(stature).

Answer (score 0):

**Slang**

A type of language that consists of words and phrases that are regarded as very informal, are more common in speech than writing, and are typically restricted to a particular context or group of people.