# What does the word "gaflooey" mean?

Tags: meaning

I've been watching **Lethal Weapon** and stumbled upon the word `gaflooey`. Here's some context:

> Roger: "What you got?"
>
> Riggs: "Part of the device. This is artwork. This is goddamn artwork."
>
> Roger: "Well, I'm glad you like it."
>
> Riggs: "You don't get it. This is real pro stuff. I haven't seen
> anything like this since the war. The CIA used it to hire mercs. They
> used the exact same setup. Mercury switches, `gaflooey`. That's heavy
> shit!"

What does the word `gaflooey` mean here?

Comment: I'm guessing it's a placeholder, like thingumajig, widget, or kadigan, used to mean an unspecified piece of complicated stuff. See this question: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/160351/term-for-using-thingy-esque-phrases-rather-than-a-common-word

Comment: kerflooey adjective (MW)
(possible alternative spelling)
ker·​floo·​ey | \ kər-ˈflü-ē  \
Definition of kerflooey
: AWRY, KAPUT

Comment: @Xanne - that's close to an answer... it fits.

Comment: They might have said *kablooey*, to indicate an explosion. Hitting the mercury switch detonates something. If they did, in fact, say *gaflooey*, I would say it means the same thing as *kablooey*.

Comment: [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/kablooey) has **kablooey** – *informal* Destroyed or ruined. @TinfoilHat just ahead.

Comment: @DjinTonic: He was fond of using the word *phooey* — not *gaflooey*. There is no indication of what *gaflooey* means there.

Comment: @TinfoilHat I've reread it and you are correct. I'll reword. Thanks

Comment: 'The lyricist Lorenz Hart was apparently fond of the word [*Phooey*]. He used it in the song “A Melican Man” in 1926: “Give Chinee man this chop suey / He’ll refuse it and say ‘Phooey’!” The following year, in the song “Whoopsie,” he used it to mean “mad” or “crazy”: “When ev’ry thing’s **gaflooey** / And life is simply phooey…” '

Comment: [**go gaflooey** v. see GO KERFLOOEY v.](https://books.google.com/books?id=5GpLcC4a5fAC&pg=PA617&lpg=PA617&dq=gaflooey+definition&source=bl&ots=2BgWR3lkz6&sig=ACfU3U2fKqd-InTgLULXu5HrkIHXqe5wlg&hl=en&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=2ahUKEwjcms7h1-H0AhVaad4KHeZtDfkQ6AF6BAgTEAM#v=onepage&q=gaflooey%20definition&f=false) Cassells' Dictionary of Slang

Comment: "**go kerflooey**, Informal. to cease functioning, especially suddenly and completely; fall apart; fail" [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/kerflooey)

Comment: @Xanne If you'd like to post an answer, you're welcome to the entries I added in comments.

Comment: @DjinTonic: Look at *kerflooey!* (with the exclamation point) in Cassell's. It's an onomatopoeia for a sudden explosion. That appears to be what happened in the video clip.

Comment: @DjinTonic You go ahead. Lots f cutting and pasting to do.

Comment: @TinfoilHat You are probably right and should answer if you like.