# What are the terms for the 6 kinds of jigsaw puzzles pieces, based on their configuration of tabs (innies vs. outies)?

Tags: terminology

What are the terms for the 6 kinds of jigsaw puzzles pieces, based on their configuration of tabs (i.e. innies vs. outies)?

I am wondering what words jigsaw afficionados and competitors use when working as a team to quickly refer to the 6 configurations possible, when solving by shape alone.

The 6 configurations I speak of are:
4 tabs
3 tabs
2 tabs (side by side)
2 tabs (opposing)
1 tab
0 tabs

Note that the question [What do you call the interconnecting bits of a puzzle piece in English?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/47667/what-do-you-call-the-interconnecting-bits-of-a-puzzle-piece-in-english) gives names for the "tabs" and the holes the tabs fit into. It doesn't **name the pieces themselves.** I'm after a word which will fit into a sentence like "I need a *fribble*" where *fribble* is a piece with a tab on opposite sides.

Comment: Also check out: [Glossary of Jigsaw Puzzle Terms](http://www.puzzlehistory.com/gloss.htm)

Comment: I can think of two other types in addition to the above - an edge piece, and a corner piece. And each of these come with different configurations of "innies" and "outies".

Comment: The top answer to the older question however says that there is no common agreement for the terms *Despite a few attempts at a comprehensive classification of piece shapes and cutting designs, there is still no generally accepted nomenclature. Manufacturers use a variety of terms, as do puzzlers. Puzzle pieces can have "loops" and "sockets", "knobs" and "holes", "tabs" and "slots", "keys" and "locks", or any of several other alternative designations.* [@ShreevatsaR](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/47672/44619)

Comment: Therefore if the manufacturers themselves cannot agree on what to call the *tabs* or *blanks*, I strongly doubt they have come up with specific terms for specific shapes according to the number of tabs or slots an individual jigsaw piece has.