# Is the word *pingle* widely understood to mean something outside the dictionary definition?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary

A **pingle** is the little tab of a jigsaw puzzle piece or some other interlocking tab of a similar nature. Or so it was in common use in my family throughout my childhood in the 1990s and early 2000s (Pacific Northwest, USA). In fact, I can't recall ever using the word *pingle* and having someone (family or friend) need my clarification as to what I was referring. However, the dictionaries do not corroborate this definition. [*Webster's*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pingle) gives a couple definitions, and [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pingle) a few more, but none of them is remotely close to the above use that I thought everyone knew. Has anyone else heard the word *pingle* in a context outside those given by the dictionaries?

Comment: If I read it somewhere I would assume it was a misspelling of "Pringle".

Comment: A presidential pingle or a regular pingle? Seriously,   I've never heard the word before, in any context, with any meaning.

Comment: A quick search for "jigsaw pingle" on Google does not turn up your definition at all in the first few pages, so I think it is likely that is not a widely used term.  It may however be a regional usage - can you add a location for your childhood remembrances?

Comment: Sounds more like something out of the Kama Sutra. Which, incidentally, reminds me that, like plumbers, we refer to such things as male and female.

Comment: possible dup - https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/47667/what-do-you-call-the-interconnecting-bits-of-a-puzzle-piece-in-english

Comment: @PhilSweet Curses, you beat me to it!

Comment: @PhilSweet: That's related, but it's not a duplicate--this question asks "Has anyone else heard the word pingle in a context outside those given by the dictionaries". It doesn't ask for an alternative expression with the same meaning.

Comment: When was your childhood?

Comment: No.  But I haven't got a better name for it.  Perhaps we should start using *pingle* in this sense.

Comment: It's not widely understood to mean **anything**.  It would possibly be most often misheard as "Pringle", referring to the hyperbolic paraboloid potato-based snack.

Answer (score 1):

The [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/144147?rskey=8mcFmf&result=4&isAdvanced=false#eid) has several
definitions of *pingle*, one of which one is similar to the definition given by @R.Dye in his answer, since deleted.

> Sc. To exert oneself, work hard or laboriously; to struggle, esp.
>   against adversity; to toil for a living.    Chiefly Sc.  a. intr. To
>   strive, contend, vie; to quarrel. Also  trans. with infinitive.
>
> b. trans. To compete fiercely with; to vie with, rival. Obs.
>
> Sc. To be hard-pressed; to be troubled, worried, or oppressed.
>
> 4. intr. Chiefly Sc. To work in a trifling or ineffectual way; to  meddle or have to do with in a petty way; to waste time, dally.   a.
>      intr. Now Eng. regional (chiefly north.). To pick at or play with 
>      one's food; to eat with little appetite, nibble
>
>    b. trans. Eng. regional (south.). To pick at or toy with (one's 
>      food). Now rare.

Also [pingle-pan](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/144146?redirectedFrom=pingle-pan#eid30277793):

> A small metal pan or shallow cooking pot, usually having a long
>   handle; a saucepan

Also, [OED](http://www.oed.com/search?searchType=dictionary&q=pingle&_searchBtn=Search)

> A small enclosed piece of land; a paddock, a close

I offer this simply because pingle is a lovely word, and we should have the definitions on the record.  I agree with @jlovegren that your meaning of the word was probably coined by your family.

**Note:**  I need to clean this up, but have a plane to catch and I can't until early next week**. I will also look for definitions in a dictionary without a pay wall.

Answer (score 1):

Could 'pingle' have been bastardized from 'pintle'? 'Pintle' and 'gudgeon' are the terms for the male and female parts of a hinge used for attaching a rudder to a boat or a shutter to a window frame. The analogy with the tab and slot on a jigsaw puzzle piece is obvious.

Comment: That's a really interesting idea. There are certainly people in my ancestry who would have known those terms.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the word was coined in your family or some other particularized context. If you are working on a jigsaw puzzle together with people it would be easy to coin vocabulary on the spot to talk about features of the jigsaw puzzle, because there is near-complete information. They can read your mind and then know what the word means, even the first time you ever use it.